# Change line thickness in emmip plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, emmeans

Can someone help me understand why I can't seem to change the line thickness with for the attached plot with the accompanying code? I want to make the lines thicker, especially for the group with the dotted type. The addition of the scale_size_manual line doesn't change anything (especially the line thickness).

I'm no expert in ggplot2 and just kind of hacked this together so no doubt I've done something wrong.
Thanks

````
emmip(mod_em_mm2, "TX_GROUP2" ~ "time", xlab = "X", ylab = "Y") + theme_bw(base_size = 20) + 
scale_color_manual(values=c("gray10", "gray10", "gray10")) +
scale_linetype_manual(name = "Group", labels = c("1", "2", "3"), values=c("solid", "dotdash", "dotted")) +
scale_size_manual(values=c(2,2,2)) +
aes(linetype = TX_GROUP2) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=df.mod_em_mm2$emmean-df.mod_em_mm2$SE, ymax=df.mod_em_mm2$emmean+df.mod_em_mm2$SE), width=.1, position=position_dodge(0.05), size = 0.8) +
guides(col = F) + 
theme(legend.position="bottom") +
ylim(0,80)
```[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpyjs.jpg
````

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't matter, this seems to have solved it:

```
emmip(mod_em_mm2, "TX_GROUP2" ~ "time", xlab = "X", ylab = "Y") + theme_bw(base_size = 20) + 
scale_color_manual(values=c("gray10", "gray10", "gray10")) +
scale_linetype_manual(name = "Group", labels = c("1", "2", "3"), values=c("solid", "dotdash", "dotted")) +
scale_size_manual(values=c(1,1,1)) +
aes(linetype = TX_GROUP2, size = TX_GROUP2) +
guides(col = F, size = F) +
theme(legend.position="bottom") +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=df.mod_em_mm2$emmean-df.mod_em_mm2$SE, ymax=df.mod_em_mm2$emmean+df.mod_em_mm2$SE), width=.1, position=position_dodge(0.05), size = 0.8) +
ylim(0,80)
```

Comment: what does df contain?